# Cannot release variable's memory with unset($var) or $var=null

Tags: php

I am trying to release the memory by useing `unset()` and `$var = null;`, but not obvious changes with just Only reduced a few KB

here is my code

```
var_dump(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024);   // output: 0.420059204102
$paginator = new Paginator( $mysql, $sql );

var_dump(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024);   // output: 0.420318603516

$ret = $paginator->getData('all', 1);
var_dump(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024);   // output: 80.0789031982

$form = $ret->items;
unset($paginator);
unset($ret);
// $paginator = null;
// $ret = null;
gc_collect_cycles();   // try to force free
var_dump(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024);   // output: 80.0779571533
```

Comment: Because `$form` still retains a reference to some data…?

Comment: @deceze  you are right, I deleted `$form = $ret->items;`, then the usage of memory down to 0.x.

Comment: but I can't understand. In my understanding, `$form = $ret->items` performed a deep copy. So `$form` should be a different variable with `$ret`. `$ret` is an `StdClass()` object, So it is an reference, but `$ret->items` is just an array data

Comment: PHP uses a copy-on-write mechanism… but even with a deep copy, the data still needs to exist in memory…!?